# Wordpress post__not_in not working in a WP_Query loop

Tags: wordpress

I need to get the related posts only in specific categories. But the 'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID(), 4) not working.

```
    <?php

      $cats_to_ignore = array(get_the_ID(), 4);
      $categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );
      $category_in = array_diff( $categories, $cats_to_ignore );

      if( count( $category_in ) == 0 ) {
            $category_in = $categories;
        }
        $cat_args = array(
            'category__in'   => $category_in,
            'posts_per_page' => 14,
            'orderby'        => 'date',
            'post__not_in'   => array(get_the_ID(), 4)
            );
        $cat_query = new WP_Query( $cat_args );
        while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();
            /* just example markup for related posts */
            echo '<h2><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
        endwhile;
        // reset $post after custom loop ends (if you need the main loop after this point)
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

It will show all posts related, but not exclude the category in 'post__not_in'